# Find G. C. F. of $(8n^3 + 8n, 2n+1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm stuck with this problem, I divided $8n^3 + 8n$ by $2n+1$ and obtained $5$, so now my G. C. F is $\gcd(2n+1, -5)$.

What's next? I can't divide $2n+1$ by $-5$.

Comment: so that means that it isn't divisible and therefore gcd is 1. Wolframalpha confirms this. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd%288n%5E3%2B8n%2C+2n%2B1%29

Comment: If $n=2$, then $2n+1$ is divisible by $5$.

Comment: Sure you can.  If $n =2$ or $n = 7$ or $n=12$ or .... But did it occur to you that maybe you are doe.  Is $\gcd(8n^3 + 8n, 2n+1) = \gcd(2n+1, 5)$ and acceptable answer?  Why or why not? If not, would *would* an acceptable answer *look* like.  Can we go further.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from the notation, it's quite likely that the exercise is *not* asking about polynomials, but about *integers*.

It's perfectly good to perform the polynomial division, because it holds for *any* value of $n$.

Since you found that the remainder is $-5$, you can conclude that the greatest common divisor of the two *integers* $8n^3+8n$ and $2n+1$ is a divisor of $5$, hence either $1$ or $5$.

It is $5$ if and only if $2n+1$ is divisible by $5$, that is, $2n\equiv4\pmod{5}$, which simplifies to $n\equiv2\pmod{5}$. Thus you have
$$
\gcd(8n^3+8n,2n+1)=
\begin{cases} 5 & n\equiv2\pmod{5} \\[4px] 1 & n\not\equiv2\pmod{5}\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, you figured out that $\gcd(8n^3 +8n, 2n+1) = \gcd(2n+1, -5)$.

And as $\gcd(\pm a, \pm b) = \gcd(a b)$ we know $\gcd(8n^3 + 8n, 2n+1) = \gcd(2n+1,5)$.

As $5$ is prime then $\gcd(2n+1, 5)$ is either $1$ or $5$.

It is $5$ if $5|2n+1$.  ANd it is $1$ if $5\not\mid 2n+1$.

And $5|2n+1 \iff$

$2n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \iff$

$2n \equiv -1 \pmod 5 \iff$

$n \equiv 2 \pmod 5$.

So the answer is:

$\gcd(8n^3+8n, 2n+1) =\begin{cases} 5 &\text{if } n\equiv 2 \pmod 5\\1&\text{if } n\not\equiv 2 \pmod 5\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

Since $8n^3+8n=(2n+1)[4n^2-2n+5]-5$, we have that $\gcd(8n^3+8n,2n+1)$ divides $5$ and so is either $1$ or $5$. Both cases do occur:

For $n=1$, we get $\gcd(8n^3+8n,2n+1)=1$.

For $n=2$, we get $\gcd(8n^3+8n,2n+1)=5$.

In fact, 
$\gcd(8n^3+8n,2n+1)=5$ iff $n \equiv 2 \bmod 5$; otherwise $\gcd(8n^3+8n,2n+1)=1$.